# Is there a Lightroom zoom-level which always fills the available screen space?

Tags: adobe-lightroom

"Fit" scales larger images down to fit the screen, preserving aspect-ratio, and without cilpping (i.e. fit taking into account both width and height). So the title of this question requests also that images smaller than the screen be scaled up (above their "native" resolution) to fill the available screen without clipping.

"Fill" doesn't seem to do this (I can't figure out what it does tbh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Library module's Survey mode. It is primarily for viewing several images at once but you can use it with just one image selected and it will zoom to fit, even above native resolution.

From the Library module, select an image and press <kbd>N</kbd> or otherwise use the menus: View -> Survey.

Comment: Thanks. Although it's a minor issue, I did notice that it is somehow not possible to use the keyboard shortcuts to increase/decrease rating while in survey mode. The 1/2/3/4/5 shortcuts work though.